# Which is more efficient: nested predicate or selecting parent element (generally traversing ancestors)

Tags: xpath

Having an XML like this:

```
<foo><bar>   foobar   </bar></foo>
```

which one of the following XPath expression is faster/efficient for selecting the 'foo' element, containing a certain 'bar' element:

```
//bar[contains(text(), 'foobar')]/..
```

or

```
//foo[bar[contains(text(), 'foobar')]]
```

?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question heavily depends on the implementation of the particular XPath engine in use.

I used `xmllint` (which is based on libxml) to perform a few measurements using the following test document:

```
<root>
<foo><bar>      </bar></foo>
[... 99998 lines ommitted ...]
<foo><bar>      </bar></foo>
<foo><bar>   foobar   </bar></foo>
</root>
```

The results are as follows:

```
> time xmllint --repeat --xpath "//bar[contains(text(), 'foobar')]/.." test.xml > /dev/null 
real    0m34.984s
user    0m45.820s
sys     0m2.332s

> time xmllint --repeat --xpath "//foo[bar[contains(text(), 'foobar')]]" test.xml > /dev/null 
real    0m40.963s
user    0m40.660s
sys     0m0.260s
```

This seems to indicate that in this particular case the first variant is faster than the second variant by a significant margin.

An even faster variant is the following:

```
> time xmllint --repeat --xpath "//foo/bar[contains(text(), 'foobar')]/.." test.xml > /dev/null 
real    0m31.945s
user    0m31.692s
sys     0m0.212s
```

This seems to indicate that using location paths having more specific node tests and avoiding predicates seems to be better, but I have no idea if this is true in the general case.